# JavaFX 8 Tableview with horizontal scrolling

Tags: java, tableview, scrollbar, javafx-8, horizontal-scrolling

How can I make a horizontal scrolling bar appear instead of squishing all the columns to the extreme minimum size? You also should still be able to resize the columns unconstrained (and make the horizontal scroll bar adjust).

[image: No horizontal scrolling bar appears]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the column take their prefer size and not make them squeeze to available screen size, you can set the `columnResizePolicy` to `UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY`

```
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```

*Since this is the default behaviour, you must have set `columnResizePolicy` to `CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY` somewhere.*

---

### Update

Here is a MCVE which shows how you can get a horizontal ScrollBar in a TableView. You can see that I do not set the `columnResizePolicy` because `UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY` is set by **default**.

Adding a MCVE for more clarity:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);
        IntStream.range(0, 15).forEach(value -> {
            TableColumn<Person, String> tableColumn = new TableColumn<>("TableColumn" + value);
            tableColumn.setPrefWidth(100.0);
            tableView.getColumns().add(tableColumn);
        });

        IntStream.range(1, 10).forEach(value -> {
            Person person = new Person("Person" + value, value);
            tableView.getItems().add(person);
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(tableView));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class Person {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        Person(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for the answer.

But the unconstrained policy makes no difference, since I've already had selected "unconstrained" in the SceneBuilder.

And also, a minimun size sadly doesn't solve the problem. With a minimun size I am able to force a horizontal scrolling bar, but I am not able to resize the columns anymore! That means I'd have to set the minimun size to a high number to even see, and be able to read, what's in the cells. This though would be very space consuming and ugly.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working example. Check it out and let me know if you want something else. :)

Comment: Embarassingly, I've found a
        `.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);`

in my code. It works now, thanks anyways.